# Opening a specific Outlook item quickly

Tags: performance, vba, excel, outlook

I have this code to open an outlook appointment item:

```
    Public Sub OpenOutlookAppt()
    Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objExpCal = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer
    Set objNavMod = objExpCal.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
    Set objNavGroup = objNavMod.NavigationGroups.GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olPeopleFoldersGroup)
    MyCalendar = objNavMod.NavigationGroups.NavigationFolders("Trip Calendar")
    EntryID = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 22)
    ReDim Newa(1 To MyCalendar.Folder.Items.count)
    r = 1
    For Each Item In MyCalendar.Folder.Items
       Newa(r) = Item.EntryID
       r = r + 1
    Next Item
    For r = 1 To UBound(Newa)
       If Newa(r) = EntryID Then
          MyCalendar.Folder.Items(r).Display
           Exit Sub
       End If
   Next r
   End Sub
```

This code works, but it is very slow, because it needs to loop through every single appointment item in the calendar folder. So my question is, would there be a faster way of doing this? Is there a way I can just simply reference the item I want to open without having to create a loop? I have the EntryID to reference the item, but I could just as easily store some other data from the item to reference it.

Comment: When reviewing code for performance it helps to have the calling function as well. But with a quick look, does the code really need 2 for loops?

Comment: I see you’re iterating through all items in folder. Maybe try to filter them first with items.restrict. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict also check  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896222/1521579

Comment: This would work with the entryid https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid

Comment: I realise that I don't need to loop twice. I can simply at the code line "Calendar.Folder.Items(r).Display" into the first loop (with an if function) to retrieve the corret appointment.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, I looked at the second link you provide, but am unable to make it work. I put in: "Calendar.GetItemFromID(EntryID).Display" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Finally figured it out! I answered this question seperately.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it worked

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to directly reference and open:

```
Set NS = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
Set myAppt = NS.GetItemFromID(EntryID)
myAppt.Display
```

Works like a dream.